# WCF Service - Getting The remote server returned an error: 413 Request Entity Too Large error

Tags: wcf-binding

WCF Service - Getting The remote server returned an error: 413 Request Entity Too Large error. This error applying on handling large data. Getting error with Content type as "XML", not for "JSON".

FYI: It is not happening for small content and happening for large content only. Is there any MAX size for XML & JSON? Kindly let me know.

```
HttpWebRequest MYrequest = null;
MYrequest = WebRequest.Create(MYUri) as HttpWebRequest;
MYrequest.Method = "POST";
MYrequest.ContentType = "application/XML";

HttpWebResponse MYresponse = (HttpWebResponse)MYrequest.GetResponse() --> Getting error.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a proper `<service>` endpoint and set the `maxReceivedMessageSize` and `maxBufferSize` on its binding resolved the issue.

Comment: All are kept as Max value.